# Como lançar exceção em SQL e tratar em C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, exceção

Estou criando *procedures* em um banco de dados SQL Server. Para exluir uma marca, primeiro eu verifico se a marca já está atrelada a algum produto antes de excluir.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Delete_MarcasProdutos
@Id int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AUX int
    SET @AUX = (select top 1 p.Id from Produtos p where p.MarcaProduto_Id = @Id AND p.Excluido = 0)

    IF(@AUX IS NOT NULL)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Não foi possível excluir esta marca, pois ela possui relacionamentos com produtos ativos';
            THROW;
        END
    ELSE
        UPDATE MarcasProdutos SET Excluido = 1 WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

O procedimento no `If` funciona? Ao lançar esta exceção, esta será a mensagem capturada pelo C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`RAISEERROR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15) com um nível de severidade de pelo menos 10 (números menores não causam exceção). Isto produzirá uma exceção no C# que pode ser capturada pelo [`SQLException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Seria algo tipo: "RAISEERROR('Não foi possível excluir esta marca, pois ela possui relacionamentos com produtos ativos', 8)"?

Comment: Só que se for 8, não vai gerar uma exceção no C#.

Comment: Aaah certo, tentarei aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: @DaviGN Você pode ver detalhadamente aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms164086.aspx

Comment: Para referência segue o equivalente Oracle ... RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ...  https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/oracle-raise_application_error/